# left, right, and middle content position

Tags: html, css, panel, navigationbar

i must use css to alter the positions; the only thing that seems to be working is the right position nav bar and the liquid layout, but the "content" and "right navigation bar" is ot being positioned properly.
I want content to be in the middle, leftnavigation on the left, and right navigation on the right.

```
<title>CSS liquid layout</title>


 <style type="text/css">

.due {
color: #ff0000;
font-weight: bold;
}

#leftnavigation{
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
width:250px;
}

#rightnavigation {
float:right;
width:250px;
height:800px;
} 
#content {
float:center;

}
    </style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" bgcolor="#ccff99">
    <div id="app">
        <div id="rightnavigation">
            <h1>Right Navigation</h1>
            <a href="http://www,google.com">link</a> <a href="http://www,google.com">Instructor</a>
            <a href="http://www,google.com">Course</a> <a href="http://www,google.com">
                Resume
                project
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Sample Content</h1>
            <p>
                This is the content section of the page. Use structural markup
                like &lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
                to keep the page valid in XHTML.
            </p>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="leftnavigation">
            <h1>Left Navigation</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="http://www,google.com">Page 1</a> <a href="http://www,google.com">Page 2</a> <a href="http://www,google.com">
                    Page
                    3
                </a> <a href="http://www,google.com">Page 4</a> <a href="http://www,google.com">Page 5</a> <br />
                Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor
                amum.
            </p>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to clean up your HTML first off - there are a lot of unclosed (and even un-opened) tags in there.  I can take a guess as to what you intended, but it's kind of hard with the current state of the code.  Please clean up the HTML and repost

Comment: Agreed - I have put it into a stack snippet for you. Please make sure the code you post here is a minimal example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are having. That will make it a lot easier for us to help. You do not need to include the `<html>` or `<head>` tags, or anything that goes inside the head. So I have removed this stuff. But I will mention that your meta tag inside the head was invalid (missing closing greater than sign).

Comment: okay,  i will clean up the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

**CSS**

```
.app {
    width: 100%
    height: 100%;
}

.due {color: #ff0000;
font-weight: bold;
}

#rightnavigation {
      float: left;
      width: 33.333%  
} 

#leftnavigation{
    float: left;
     width: 33.333%

}

#content {
   float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="app">

    <div id="leftnavigation">
        <h1> Left Navigation </h1>
    </div>

     <div id="content"></div>

      <div id="rightnavigation"> 
        <h1>Right Navigation</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's a live demo of the example - [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/brmbL121/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your HTML and CSS that need to be addressed before changing the styles to accomplish what you need.

1. In your HTML, there are still some unclosed tags. Especially the `<div id="rightnavigation">` tag is never closed, so styles applied to `#rightnavigation` are actually applied to the entire page.
2. In your CSS, you apply a style to `div.content`.  But that div has an **id** of `content`, not a **class**. The identifier should be `div#content`.
3. In your CSS, you give the `div` with id `leftnavigation` a position of "left". This should be "absolute" instead.
4. Once that is all cleaned up, the left nav is on the left, the content is in the center, and the right nav is on the right. But the center content overlaps the right nav (I assume that is unwanted behavior). To clean that up, without changing the HTML any more, you need to give your sections widths, and set their positions based on the width of their neighboring elements.

Your HTML:

```
<div id="rightnavigation"> 
    <h1>Right Navigation</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Sample Content</h1>
    <p>This is the content section of the page. Use structural markup
    like &lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    to keep the page valid in XHTML.</p>
    <p>The styled document should  look like your printed version/screenshot.  
    Add styles to the left navigation links to give them borders and a 
    background color that changes when moused over (hint: Define navigation 
    links as display:block;). For the right side links, use a different 
    background color change and border as ashown.  
    Make the center column "liquid" or "elastic." Use an external (linked) 
    CSS file. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. 
    Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit 
    dolor amum. 
    Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. </p>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p> Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. 
    Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. 
    Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. </p>
    <p><span class="due">Due Tuesday, September 22.</span> Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. 
    Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. 
    Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. </p>
</div>
<div id="leftnavigation"> 
    <h1>Left Navigation</h1> 
    <p><br>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amum. </p>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#rightnavigation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 25%;
} 

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
}

#leftnavigation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 25%;
}

.due {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```